# Ruling regarding adultery in this specific situation?

Tags: nikah, adultery

Assalam alaykum.

I wish to be brief while stating the details.

• Nikkah for 3 years. Attempted vaginal intercourse with wife. However there was never any penetration as she had a health condition (vaginismus).

• I am guilty of Adultery while married (nikkah). Confessed to wife, and as well my brother and sister-in-law heard my confession.

• I've read that my nikkah is valid. However, I've also read that there are conditions to be considered a "muhsan". E.g. must be vaginal penetration to classify as muhsan.

Does anyone know if I am [classified as a "muhsan"](https://sunnah.com/urn/511350) or not? A source from Sunnah.com mentions specifically a muhsan is نَكَحَ إِحْدَاهُنَّ فَأَصَابَهَا, or "nikkah with penetration". The only other detailed source I have is [IslamWeb](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/725/definition-of-muhsan) which frankly does not seem reputable. Who can I talk to to find out more information? Specifically would like to reach out to a scholar of Fiqh who is familiar with rulings from each of the four schools. I do not have a specific school I prescribe to as I do not know enough.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam.